# Parameterize Linked Services Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, parameter-passing, azure-data-factory, linked-service

I have Database Username , Servername, hostand other details that are stored in Table. I wanted to make a Linked Service that can use the connection details from these table and store it in parameter.

As of now i am hardcoding these details in parameters created in linked service but I want a generic linked service that can take details from table or from pipeline parameter.

Comment: You would *have* to use dynamic to achieve this, and **safely** inject the information into your queries.

Comment: Yes but how becasue i am not able to add values in parameter  fetched from Databaase. Can you please let me know how we can acheive this

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no such feature available in Azure Data Factory which allows to parameterize the Linked Service or the pipeline where values are stored in a out source Table or file. You need to define the values in ADF only.

The standard and only way possible is to parameterize a linked service and pass dynamic values at run time by defining the values in ADF. For example, if you want to connect to different databases on the same logical SQL server, you can now parameterize the database name in the linked service definition. This prevents you from having to create a linked service for each database on the logical SQL server.

> You can use parameters to pass external values into pipelines,
> datasets, linked services, and data flows. Once the parameter has been
> passed into the resource, it cannot be changed. By parameterizing
> resources, you can reuse them with different values each time.
> Parameters can be used individually or as a part of expressions. JSON
> values in the definition can be literal or expressions that are
> evaluated at runtime.

The official document [Parameterize linked services in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services?tabs=data-factory) will help you to understand the complete fundamentals.